# Collision between a line and a face

Tags: java, 3d, line, collision, plane

Ok, so on the internet, I have seen equations for solving this, but they require the normal of the plane, and are a lot higher math than I know.

Basically, if I have an x,y,z position (as well as x,y,z rotations) for my ray, and x,y,z for three points that represent my plane, How would I solve for the point of collision?

I have done 2D collisions before, but I am clueless on how this would work in 3D. Also, I work in java, though I understand C# well enough.

Thanks to the answer below, I was able to find the normal of my face. This then allowed me to, through trial and error and http://geomalgorithms.com/a05-_intersect-1.html, come up with the following code (hand made vector math excluded):

```
Vertice Vertice1 = faces.get(f).getV1();
Vertice Vertice2 = faces.get(f).getV2();
Vertice Vertice3 = faces.get(f).getV3();

Vector v1 = vt.subtractVertices(Vertice2, Vertice1);
Vector v2 = vt.subtractVertices(Vertice3, Vertice1);
Vector normal = vt.dotProduct(v1, v2);

//formula = -(ax + by + cz + d)/n * u where a,b,c = normal(x,y,z) and where u = the vector of the ray from camX,camY,camZ,
// with a rotation of localRotX,localRotY,localRotZ

double Collision = 
                 -(normal.x*camX + normal.y*camY + normal.z*camZ) / vt.dotProduct(normal, vt.subtractVertices(camX,camY,camZ,
                 camX + Math.sin(localRotY)*Math.cos(localRotX),camY + Math.cos(localRotY)*Math.cos(localRotX),camZ + Math.sin(localRotX)));
```

This code, mathimatically should work, but I have yet to properly test the code. Tough I will continue working on this, I consider this topic finished. Thank you.

Comment: If people would at least tell me why they downvoted me, then at least it would be beneficial.

Comment: They are most likely downvoting because you didn't show any attempts you have already made at the problem (code, equation, etc.). I understand you're probably stuck with where to go, so I've tried to provide a hint at progressing. Please update your question as you figure more out, as I'm sure you're not the only one working on this type of problem.

Comment: I have to make some corrections here: the line `Vector normal = vt.dotProduct ...` should use the cross product instead. Those are two very different things. The dot product returns a scalar (i.e. one-dimensional value), where cross product returns a vector.

Next, the formula does not yield a vector, it yields a single scalar. There is no division of vectors. The bottom terms of the equation (`n * u`), is the dot product of n and u, which yields a scalar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be very helpful to post one of the equations that you think would work for your situation. Without more information, I can only suggest using basic linear algebra to get the normal vector for the plane from the data you have.

In R<sup>3</sup> (a.k.a. 3d math), the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of two vectors will yield a vector that is perpendicular to the two vectors. A plane normal vector is a vector that is perpendicular to the plane.

You can get two vectors that lie in your plane from the three points you mentioned. Let's call them A, B, and C.

```
v1 = B - A

v2 = C - A

normal = v1 x v2
```

Stackoverflow doesn't have Mathjax formatting so that's a little ugly, but you should get the idea: construct two vectors from your three points in the plane, take the cross product of your two vectors, and then you have a normal vector. You should then be closer to adapting the equation to your needs.